# Error while mapping shared library

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk

I'm trying to debug my Android app (I'm using the libdash library through NDK) as a native application, and I'm having this error:

```
Error while mapping shared library sections:
`/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjpeg.so': not in executable format: File format not recognized
warning: Could not load shared library symbols for 92 libraries, e.g. /system/bin/linker.
Use the "info sharedlibrary" command to see the complete listing.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
warning: Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.
GDB will retry eventurally.  Meanwhile, it is likely
that GDB is unable to debug shared library initializers
or resolve pending breakpoints after dlopen().
```

this is the library that i'm trying to use 
http://www.bitmovin.net/libdash/

Comment: What format is the library in?  Why is this in the C section?  Android apps are written in java.

Comment: Thx for answering.
the library has C and C++ files, android apps is written in java and i use  System.loadLibrary(libname.so) to use native function.

Comment: You can't use C/C++ libraries in an android application.  You can only use some C/C++ libraries in the kernel, which you're not modifying (I assume). You need to go find a java implementation of the library (and all those library dependencies if there are any).

Comment: I'm using NDK : 
The NDK is a toolset that allows you to implement parts of your app using native-code languages such as C and C++. For certain types of apps, this can be helpful so you can reuse existing code libraries written in these languages, but most apps do not need the Android NDK.

Comment: Something very strange is going on here - it's as if the NDK GDB is trying to open a library **for the development machine** to try to reference the code running on the device.  That shouldn't be happening.  That said, is this actually a fatal error?  Generally you would not debug through a platform library unless you are working on platform code (in which case you are probably using your own version, with sources) or are being curious.

Comment: in fact i'm using my own version with sources yes.

Answer (score 0):

http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/

Follow these directions.  You need to take the library and put it somewhere special.

Comment: It does not seem like there's any solution there.  Please specify exactly what recommendation from this page you think would help?  Also, please consider deleting your mistaken comments from the question itself, as they are not helping the search for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue appears to be that you are cross compiling for Android, yet you haven't set your shared library lookup path.  The result is that gdb is looking in your host system path to find the shared libraries instead.

Your host system is the system you run the build of your code on (your PC probably).  Your target system is the system you're going to run the resulting "executable" on (some Android device).  That's why it's called cross compiling.  Since the two systems aren't the same, you need to make sure you're using a cross compiled version of gdb (one that knows your target and host types), which was probably provided with the Android SDK, and you also need to make sure you set the search path for the shared libraries.

You should check the general GDB documentation for details, but the method I prefer for setting my cross-compiled library paths is to set the solib-absolute-path.  You can do that by running the following from within GDB:

```
(gdb) set solib-absolute-path <path to root directory all Android shared libraries are under>
```

This requires that you have the same directory structure as your Android file system with regard to library paths somewhere on your PC.

An alternate and more portable way of doing it is to set the solib-search-path so it will search the Android library locations within the SDK on your PC rather than your PC's default library search path, but for details on that you'll have to read the GDB documentation since I don't use it often enough to help much more.